# Insertion sorting an double array list, first item doesn't get sorted

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

arraylist insertion sorting in the sorting class:

```
public void insertionSort(ArrayList <Double>list){
    double temp;
    int  previousIndex;

    for(int index = 1; index < list.size(); index++){
        temp = list.get(index);
        previousIndex = index - 1;
        while((list.get(previousIndex) > temp) && (previousIndex > 0)){
            list.set((previousIndex+1), list.get(previousIndex));
            previousIndex-=1;
        }
        if(list.get(previousIndex) > temp){
            list.set((previousIndex+1), list.get(previousIndex));
           list.set((previousIndex+1), temp);
        }else{
           list.set((previousIndex+1), temp);
        }
    } 
}
```

main class:

```
package sorts;

import java.util.*;

public class TestSorts {


public static void displayArrayList(ArrayList <Double> list){
    for (int i=0; i<list.size();i++){
        System.out.print(list.get(i)+" \n");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");       
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int numItems,searchNum,location;
    Sorts sort=new Sorts();

    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int numItems,searchNum,location;
    Sorts sort=new Sorts();
    System.out.print("Enter the number of elements: ");
    numItems=in.nextInt();

    ArrayList <Double> list=new ArrayList<>();


    for (int i=0;i<numItems;i++){
        list.add((int)100*Math.random());
    }


    System.out.println("Unsorted: ");
    displayArrayList(list);
    sort.insertionSort(list);
    System.out.println("Sorted: ");
    displayArrayList(list);               

  }  
}
```

basically what's happening right now is that numbers will be generated fine, and sorted fine, except for when it's sorted, the very first item in the sorted list will be incorrect. such as:

Unsorted:

```
58.754608713273925 

77.15776272269233 

61.752499151303795 

1.9942069463339207 

55.30460705281677 

78.06371704304172
```

Sorted:

```
58.754608713273925

1.9942069463339207 

55.30460705281677 

61.752499151303795 

77.15776272269233 

78.06371704304172
```

so it seems everything sorts fine but the very first random number in the list never gets sorted, and ends up staying in the exact same position as before.

Comment: Well, since you explicitly start your insert at index 1, that'll happen ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void insertionSort(ArrayList<Double> list) {
        double temp;
        int previousIndex;

        for (int index = 1; index < list.size(); index++) {
            temp = list.get(index);
            previousIndex = index - 1;
            while (previousIndex >= 0 && (list.get(previousIndex) > temp)) {
                list.set((previousIndex + 1), list.get(previousIndex));
                previousIndex -= 1;
            }
            if (previousIndex >= 0 && list.get(previousIndex) > temp) {
                list.set((previousIndex + 1), list.get(previousIndex));
                list.set((previousIndex + 1), temp);
            } else {
                list.set((previousIndex + 1), temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain to me why this works after changing it to >=0 instead of =0? I changed this code from what was originally made for an int array, and =0 works for an array but not for an arraylist, and I'm not sure why this is

Comment: Because of that you want to change positions in while loop, right? But in you sorting code, the condition of while loop is previousIndex > 0, so when previousIndex is 0 (the first random number), the code in while loop could not work, I think that`s the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`index = 1` should be `index = 0` in your sort routine.  Currently, you are skipping the first item in your List, which is stored at index zero.

Comment: would that matter though? because isn't index of 0 still accessed by my previousindex=index-1?